# Using ORDER BY RAND() with multiple WHERE clauses mysql

Tags: php, mysql, random, sql-order-by

I know that order by rand() isn't the fastest way of drawing a random value from a database, but my database is small, and at this point; I just want it to work! haha. Here's my code:

```
include('includes/dbc.php');
$top_query = "SELECT * FROM top WHERE 'occasion_id =" . $occasion . "' AND 'temperature_id = " . $temperature . "' AND 'user_id = " . $user_id . "'ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
$top_result = mysqli_query($dbc, $top_query) or die (' The top SELECT query is broken.');
mysqli_close ($dbc);

while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($top_result)) {
    echo 'This top has an id of:' . $row['top_id']  . '<br> ';
    echo 'Does this top require pants?' . $row['needs_pants']  . '<br>';
    echo 'What\'s the colour id of this top?' . $row['colour_id'] . '<br>';
    echo  $row['value'];
}
```

For some reason this just doesn't work and I will just show up blank when I try to run my array. It worked before I threw in the order by "rand() limit 1" bit, but obviously I got every value instead of just one random one.

Can anyone see where I went wrong? Thanks so much!

Comment: You should really use prepared statements, especially since you are already using `mysqli`

Comment: "my database is small [...] I just want it to work!" Nothing wrong with that approach. Build for functionality, security, maintainability and readability... optimize later when it's proven that it's necessary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your query is malformed. It's not *dying*, it's just not returning results.

Note the errant single quotes:

```
$top_query = "SELECT * FROM top WHERE 'occasion_id =" . $occasion . "' AND 'temperature_id = " . $temperature . "' AND 'user_id = " . $user_id . "'ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
```

You can prove this by outputting your query then running it in MySQL directly (such as through PHPMyAdmin):

```
echo $top_query;
```

Also functions like [`mysqli_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) and [`mysqli_num_rows()`](http://php.net/mysqli_num_rows) help determine query results.

To move you on your way, the SQL should look more like:

```
$top_query = "SELECT * FROM top WHERE occasion_id = '" . $occasion . "' AND temperature_id = '" . $temperature . "' AND user_id = '" . $user_id . "' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
```

Some additional notes:

- Read up on [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).
- Familiarize yourself with when you need to quote [literal values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/literals.html) in MySQL. In your case these are all ID columns (theoretically integers) and therefore don't need to be quoted.
- Be mindful not to prematurely close your MySQL connection. PHP will actually do this automatically at the end of the script.
- As commented by **webbiedave**, also look into [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

Comment: I kind of figured it wasn't dying, since my "or die" statement wan't showing up. Do you know what exactly is malformed about it & how would I fix that? thanks

Comment: She should also use parameterized queries and not have to worry about quotes at all!

Comment: I see where I went wrong. Those darn'ed quotations can get confusing. It works now; thanks so much!